# epoll_wait seems to get stuck on EPOLLRDHUP

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, epoll

So I have some code that looks like this:

```
for (;;) {
        errno=0;
        epoll_event e = {};
        auto wait_r = epoll_wait(g.epoll_fd, &e, 1, 0);
        if (wait_r==0) break;
        if(wait_r ==-1 && errno==EINTR) {
            printf("got EINTR\n");
            continue;
        }
        assert(wait_r == 1);

        auto& c = *(Context*)e.data.ptr;

        if(e.events & EPOLLERR ) {

            int       error = 0;
            socklen_t errlen = sizeof(error);
            auto r1 =getsockopt(c.socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (void *)&error, &errlen);
            assert(r1==0);
            printf("Got EPOLLERR 2 %s\n", strerror(error));
        }


        if(e.events & EPOLLRDHUP || e.events & EPOLLHUP ) {
            if (e.events & EPOLLRDHUP) {
                printf("got to EPOLLRDHUP\n");
            }
            if (e.events & EPOLLHUP) {
                printf("got to EPOLLHUP\n");
            }
            //continue; // keeps hitting this for same connections
            break;
        }

        if (e.events & EPOLLIN) {

            // Does a bunch of reads...
        }
    }
}
```

A single socket will getting stuck in the `EPOLLRDHUP || EPOLLHUP` case.  The socket is likely closed,  when I try to close it or do EPOLL_CTL_DEL I get a EBADFD.  It was my understanding that epoll will automatically get rid of any dead sockets, but this doesn't seem to be the case... any ideas?

One other possible issue is that on the socket I am using recvmsg/sendmsg and I'm sending file descriptors between processes, over these sockets, which are unix domain stream sockets.  I have tried to do a final recvmsg on it, but that fails as well... Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend that your code call `close` before it's done processing the `EPOLLHUP` event. Note that `EPOLLHUP` indicates the other party closed the connection - but your code didn't close the connection just yet. Since the `fd` is still open on your side, `epoll` will keep polling it.

Comment: @myst when I try to close it, it fails with bad file descriptor, in this case.  But thank you for the recommendation for the general case.

Comment: I'm certain the client `fd` (not the `g.epoll_fd`) must be closed by your code in order to release it's resources. Your code isn't a complete example, so there's a limit to how much I can review. I'm not sure which function call causes the `EBADFD` or what value you pass to `close`. In fact, I'm not even sure where you store the event's `fd` value. You can store it in the event, but I sometimes use the event to store a pointer to an object that contains the `fd` data as well as other information... and maybe the error occurs because you aren't storing it anywhere. I can't tell.

Comment: @myst Ok, I'm working a better, more complete minimal example of my issue.

Comment: @Myst sorry for the long wait, but I eventually figured it out, see my answer below.  I created a minimal version of my code, but it didn't exhibit the problem, I was quite perplexed for a while, but now the solution seems obvious....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my issue, the solution was to change an a line like this:

```
c.socket = accept(g.server_socket, NULL, NULL);
```

to this:

```
c.socket = accept4(g.server_socket, NULL, NULL, SOCK_CLOEXEC);
```

If anyone else has this issue, look out for `dup()` and `exec()` calls.  A `dup()` can cause `epoll` to act like it's not closed, even though you have already closed the fd that you added to `epoll`. `epoll` will only recognize that its closed once all copies of the fd are closed.  `exec()` will essentially do the same thing as a `dup()` for every fd that you have that wasn't created with the `SOCK_CLOEXEC` flag...